# Can we have a different __name__ attribute for different aliasess of a Python class?

Tags: python, alias, classname

I have a very simple generic class with keyword arguments only:

```
class genObj(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for kwa in kwargs:
            self.__setattr__(kwa, kwargs[kwa])
```

Now I want to use this for different objects, with different parameters, using the alias name like the following:

```
rectangle = genObj
rr = rectangle(width=3, height=1)

circle = genObj
cc = circle(radius=2)
```

It works OK. No problem. What I want is the class to know with what alias name it is used. Now if I ask:

```
rr.__class__.__name__
>> "genObj"

cc.__class__.__name__
>> "genObj"
```

What I want is to get "rect" for the rr query, and "circle" for the cc query.
Is it possible at all? How?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the way you have it set up, `circle` and `rectangle` are the same object (same type in this case) so `circle.__name__ is rectangle.__name__`. The cleanest way to get what you what imo, is to make `circle` and `rectangle` both sub-classes of `genObj`. You could do something like this:

```
class genBase(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for kwa in kwargs:
            self.__setattr__(kwa, kwargs[kwa])

def genObj(name):
    return type(name, (genBase,), {})

circle = genObj("circle")
print issubclass(circle, genBase)
# True
c = circle(r=2)
print type(c).__name__
# circle
```